# Обработка rss-канала. Хml-формат с тегами span

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Есть rss-канал https://rp5.ru/rss/4475/ru (xml-формат)
Хочу выудить информацию о температуре воздуха, но они обновили и теперь там тал присутствовать тег `span` каким-то образом он всё ломает. Т.е. не даёт отображение температуры внутри `span`
Делаю выпорку так:

```
foreach ( $xml->entry as $key => $item ) /* тут вроде всё нормально */  
 { 
    $weather_string_line = $item->summary; 
 }

foreach ( $xml->entry->summary as $key => $item )  /* тут меня терзают смутные сомнения */
 { 
    $weather_string_line_span = $item->span; 
 }
```

Пример работы php: https://krasnovosti.ru/soft/weather_string_line.php
Как видно из примера ловится лишь то что в `<span class="was_t">было</span>`
А как поймать все значения в этих `span`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так (c переводом $value в массив):

```
$url = 'https://rp5.ru/rss/4475/ru';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ( $xml->entry as $key => $item ) /* тут вроде всё нормально */
{
    $weather_string_line = $item->summary->span;
    foreach ($weather_string_line as $key=>$value){
        $array =  (array) $value;
        $temp1 = $array[0];
        print_r($temp1);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
было+2.3+0.7+3.2°C
```